# can't read ArrayList properly in JAVA EE

Tags: java, object, servlets, arraylist

I try to understand why an ArrayList that I've built from an SQL query won't be read properly when passed to a Servlet.

```
public ArrayList<Product> showEntireStock() throws BusinessException{

    ArrayList<Product> listeProduct = new ArrayList<Product>();


    try(Connection cnx =ConnectionProvider.getConnection(); PreparedStatement st = cnx.prepareStatement(SHOW_ALL);) {
        ResultSet rs= null;
        Product liquide = new Liquid();


        rs= st.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()) {

            liquide.setNom(rs.getString("nameProduct"));
            liquide.setDesignation(rs.getString("designationProduct"));
            liquide.setCategory(rs.getInt("categorieProduct"));
            liquide.setId(rs.getInt("idProduct"));
            **System.out.println(liquide.toString());**
            listeProduct.add(liquide);

        }

    }catch(Exception e) {


        BusinessException busy = new BusinessException();
        busy.ajouterErreur(ListeCodeErreur.STOCK_VIDE);
        busy.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listeProduct;

}
```

The System.out.println() in this method does show that attributes are getting filled with the right information (only the id can change here, the other attributes are hard coded for test)

```
Product [id=2, nom=Champagne, designation=nouveau liquide, imagePath=null, price=0.0, category=1]
    Product [id=3, nom=Champagne, designation=nouveau liquide, imagePath=null, price=0.0, category=1]
    Product [id=4, nom=Champagne, designation=nouveau liquide, imagePath=null, price=0.0, category=1]
    Product [id=5, nom=Champagne, designation=nouveau liquide, imagePath=null, price=0.0, category=1]
    Product [id=6, nom=Champagne, designation=nouveau liquide, imagePath=null, price=0.0, category=1]
    Product [id=7, nom=Champagne, designation=nouveau liquide, imagePath=null, price=0.0, category=1]
    Product [id=8, nom=Champagne, designation=nouveau liquide, imagePath=null, price=0.0, category=1]
    Product [id=9, nom=Champagne, designation=nouveau liquide, imagePath=null, price=0.0, category=1]
    Product [id=10, nom=Champagne, designation=nouveau liquide, imagePath=null, price=0.0, category=1]
```

BUT when I try to read it in a Servelt, the toString()method of the Product object contained in the ArrayList only shows the last element and print it as many times as there are objects in the ArrayList.

```
@WebServlet("/Stock")
public class Stock extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        StockDAOImpl stock = new StockDAOImpl();
        ArrayList<Product> listeProduct = new ArrayList<>();


        try {
            listeProduct = stock.showEntireStock();
            request.setAttribute("stock", listeProduct);

    for (Product p : listeProduct) {

        System.out.println(p.toString());
    }
        } catch (BusinessException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Stock.jsp").forward(request, response);


    }
```

```
   Product [id=10, nom=Champagne, designation=nouveau liquide, imagePath=null, price=0.0, category=1]
   Product [id=10, nom=Champagne, designation=nouveau liquide, imagePath=null, price=0.0, category=1]
   Product [id=10, nom=Champagne, designation=nouveau liquide, imagePath=null, price=0.0, category=1]
   Product [id=10, nom=Champagne, designation=nouveau liquide, imagePath=null, price=0.0, category=1]
   Product [id=10, nom=Champagne, designation=nouveau liquide, imagePath=null, price=0.0, category=1]
   Product [id=10, nom=Champagne, designation=nouveau liquide, imagePath=null, price=0.0, category=1]
   Product [id=10, nom=Champagne, designation=nouveau liquide, imagePath=null, price=0.0, category=1]
   Product [id=10, nom=Champagne, designation=nouveau liquide, imagePath=null, price=0.0, category=1]
```

I have no idea why it's doing this and can't find an article that would give a hint.No error message either. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You override the same object in every iteration. You have to create a new object in the iteration. So the constructor call must instide the `while` loop

```
        rs= st.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()) {
            Product liquide = new Liquid();

            liquide.setNom(rs.getString("nameProduct"));
            liquide.setDesignation(rs.getString("designationProduct"));
            liquide.setCategory(rs.getInt("categorieProduct"));
            liquide.setId(rs.getInt("idProduct"));
            **System.out.println(liquide.toString());**
            listeProduct.add(liquide);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `showEntireStock`, you only create and add a single `Product` to `ArrayList`.

You're creating a product, changing it, adding it to the list, *then changing that same product and adding it again*.

You need to create a new product on each iteration of the loop. Move

```
Product liquide = new Liquid();
```

to the inside of the loop.

Comment: Of course! thank you so much! it does work now...many many thanx!!